# Rails HTML Table: <tr> tag doesn't do anything

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

```
<% @user.workstations.each do |ws| %>
  <tr class="red">
    <td class="td_workstation"> <%= ws.name %> </td>
    <td class="td_workstation"> <%= ws.applications %> </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

The class "red" is supposed to make the background red, but it doesn't do anything. Why isn't it affecting the rows??????

```
.red {
  background: red;
  font-size: 60px;
}

.td_workstation, .th_workstation {
border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
```

Comment: Why not `each`? It kills me inside!

Comment: Because I'm a rails noobie and I don't know what that is :p

Comment: I just edited your question. Please have a look at it.

Comment: Though how is that better? If anything, it looks less intuitive to me

Comment: You are a beginner, so it may not look that intuitive right now, but that's _the Rails way_ of doing things. You are gonna find `each` everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Try in your stylesheet changing the .red class to:

```
tr.red td {
  background-color: red;
  border-collapse:collapse; //Throw this border-collapse in if you want to remove the white margins around each cell after you change the background.
  font-size: 60px;
}
```

Comment: Didn't work. I should also mention that the font doesn't work either.

Comment: Are you sure your css file is being loaded appropriately?  Put these styles directly in your app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss file for now to make sure they're at least being loaded.

Comment: When I add this class directly to the "td" class, it works fine. However, that's not the behavior I want -- I want to highlight the entire row.

Comment: The border-collapse had no impact either.

Comment: That's telling it to add background colors to all table cells that have the parent tr.red   Mark as correct if that helped!